# Is there a way to dynamically change the text of a textBox in Visual Studio with C# so that the value is a sum of values from other textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I need to have a text box that dynamically changes as values in other text boxes are being changed, and the value (would be an integer converted to string) of the "Total" textbox has to have the sum of the other values. Is there a way to do this without having to create a TextChanged event for each of the other textboxes?

Comment: *Is there a way to do this without having to create a TextChanged event for each of the other textboxes?* -

Yes, but it's probably slightly more work and I highly doubt it will be anything you've been taught so it'll be blindingly obvious someone on the internet did it for you

Comment: @JohnG well, "have to" is such a strong phrase..

Comment: How to make that without having to create a "TextChanged" method for every other box?

Comment: Use NumericUpDown controls instead. They're like textboxes but more numeric focused/easier to work with in the context of numbers

Comment: I would have used NumericUpDown controls but I am using DateTime values in the boxes I am talking about, but its a useful suggestion thank you

Comment: @dannkis - Unless there is some relevance to saying "I am doing this project for school" then we don't add that kind of information to questions. We try to have questions that a clear and concise without salutations, thank yous, or social fillers.

Comment: Then use a DateTimePicker. How you add up multiple dates, I've no idea..

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

Label1.text= textbox1.value + textbox2.value + textbox3.value +.....

Comment: I need it to change dynamically so the problem is I don't know where to put this code so it is being executed every time a value from the other text boxes has been changed

Comment: That will not work dynamically... if one of the text boxes changes... you will have to call the code again.

Comment: Properties written by Microsoft follow c# naming guidelines; they're PascalCase. A TextBox doesn't have a Value property. If you could put a little more effort into your answer it would be wonderful

Comment: Yeah sorry i shouldnt answer from my phone theres also no way of commenting till someelse did (using ecosia browser). However dont know what u guys see as dynamically because at forms i made the labeltext changes soon as a textbox changes. But elseways putting the formula i gave in every textbox clicked event should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio, go to `Form1.cs[Design]` and leftclick a textbox once, then, on the right hand lower side, click the lightning that says `events`. Search for `TextChanged` and type in how you would like the event to be named (e.g. `textBox1_TextChanged`). on hitting enter, you should automatically be sent to Form1.cs, where a new void was created. There, insert the code proposed by Stefanovici (although change textbox1.value to textbox1.text) and **rinse and repeat for each textbox**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //should automatically be created
{
    Label1.text= textbox1.text + textbox2.text + textbox3.text +.....
}
```

You can also bind multiple textboxes to the same event. Naming the event identical for every textbox will call the event when either textbox was changed, reducing the amount of code

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't want to create `TextChanged` event handlers for each `TextBox` because it is a tedious job. There's a way to make it easy.

Start with a field like this:

```
private TextBox[] textBoxes = null;
```

Then you can set up all of the `TextChanged` event handlers like this:

```
textBoxes = new []
{
    textBox1, textBox2, textBox3,
    textBox4, textBox5,
};

foreach (var tb in textBoxes)
{
    tb.TextChanged += (_, _) => UpdateTotal();
}
```

Now the `UpdateTotals` can be defined any way you want. Here's my version:

```
private void UpdateTotal()
{
    var value =
        textBoxes
            .Select(x =>
                double.TryParse(x.Text, out double value)
                    ? value
                    : 0.0)
            .Sum();
            
    textBoxTotal.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In my case, not all textboxes need to have a value and some of them would be left empty. Also why are you changing my answer what is the problem of it being for a school project I dont understand xD?

Comment: @dannkis - I've updated the answer to ignore empty or non-numerical data.

Comment: @dannkis - We don't add superfluous text to questions. The comment about it being a school project didn't add any value to the question, IMHO, so I took it out. Do you think it adds value?

Comment: It just kinda makes people not go as hard on me if I say something that may be incorrect that is why I decided to add it. Also your solution looks great I am just wondering how would you make this to work with DateTime values?

Comment: @dannkis - Structurally it's the same for `DateTime`. You just need to work out how to parse the text into a `DateTime`.

Comment: tb.TextChanged += (_, _) => UpdateTotal(); I get a 'lamda discard parameters is not available in C# 7.3.';

Comment: textBoxes.Select(x => DateTime.TryParse(x.Text, out DateTime value) ? value : 0.0).Sum(); I get an error with the .Select method I get Compiler Error CS0411

Comment: @dannkis - You can give the lambda some dummy variables like `(foo, bar) =>` and that should work fine. Also, make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code to make the `Select` work.

Comment: I still don't understand where I am supposed to put these methods? if I assign them to a button it wouldn't be dynamic. If I declare them into the TextChanged method then it is the same as calling a method that adds them all up.

Comment: @dannkis - You are correct it wouldn't be in a button click or a text box text changed event. I wonder if you can find any code that runs when the form first opens?

Comment: @dannkis - You have also not showed us any code in your question. Had you put code in there then I would have had somewhere to put my code to show you. You should show code when asking a question.